# How servers works with web sockets?

Tags: web, websocket

How web servers serve multiply requests simultaneously. I think that sockets are used during the communication betwen client and server. But what if two clients try to connect one socket at one time? This socket will be used and second client could not be connected?

Comment: It is up to the operating system and web server to make sure that only one client connects to a single socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servers can accept and service multiple client connections at the same time, usually by using multiple threads, overlapped/asynchronous I/O, or even forking multiple processes.  But in any case, multiple clients are serviced in parallel to each other.  A new client connection is refused only if the server has run out of resources to accept more clients.